# Deploying React app to github pages. GET ... net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github-pages

GitHub: https://github.com/Justin-Schneider/portfolio

Link to Page: https://justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/

The Link brings up nothing and I get the following two Errors:

```
GET https://justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/static/css/main.233e2870.css net::ERR_ABORTED
GET https://justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/static/js/main.c60b5716.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

npm run deploy executes correctly

package.json

```
{
"name": "my-website",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"homepage": "justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio",
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.2.0",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
  "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
},
"scripts": {
  "deploy" : "npm run build&&gh-pages -d build",
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "gh-pages": "^1.1.0"
}
}
```

Comment: I get `GET Status Code:404` `https://justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/static/css/main.233e2870.css` and `https://justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/static/js/main.c60b5716.js` do you have those files with that exact name and path? Looks like you maybe typoed the path or similar?

Comment: Yes, I have those files they are listed in my repo. However they are `https://justin-schneide‌​r.github.io/portfoli‌​o/static/css/main.23‌​3e2870.css` and not `https://justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/justin-schneide‌​r.github.io/portfoli‌​o/static/css/main.23‌​3e2870.css` not sure why its being repetitive. Also the errors I listed were after asking for "verbose" errors.

Comment: It seems that you created GitHub pages in the `project` way, but I can't find your index.html or any css or js files in your repo here: https://github.com/Justin-Schneider/portfolio ?

Comment: They are in the gh-pages branch, and the page's source is set to said branch.

Answer (score 3):

```
"homepage": "."
```

**This will Work!**

As @Maksim Luzik have described the problem above.

We need to replace our URL in package.json with a '.' for the path.

For example :-
This..

> ***https://{username}.github.io/portfolio***/justinschneider.github.io/portfolio/static/css/main.233e2870.css

will be...

> ./justinschneider.github.io/portfolio/static/css/main.233e2870.css

Hope you will get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

in your nodejs make sure that you make the build folder static so it can be accessed from the browser

```
   app.use(express.static('./client/build/'));
   app.use('/', express.static('./client/build/index.html'));
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand by what you mean by "in your nodejs" could you perhaps reference a file or something?

Comment: in your server file if you use express 
add  the above lines with you relative paths  to make the build of react js file accessible

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your `react-scripts build` react is building with relative path, thus referencing incorrectly `https://justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/static/css/main.233e2870.css` instead of your correct url: `https://justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio/static/css/main.233e2870.css`. If you can't change the dist path for the css and js in react-build, you can consider using https://webpack.js.org/ as css and js bundler, there you can set your options for static directory in a way that you can reference them correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was actually an easy fix. I made a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In my package.json I needed "https://justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio" and not simply "justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio"

my updated package.json

```
{
"name": "my-website",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"homepage": "https://justin-schneider.github.io/portfolio",
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.2.0",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
  "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
 },
"scripts": {
  "deploy" : "npm run build&&gh-pages -d build",
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
"devDependencies": {
  "gh-pages": "^1.1.0"
}
}
```